# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:1

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-build

I don't know where the error is and how to remove it. I'm new to sencha touch and phonegap.
here is my app.js file

// DO NOT DELETE - this directive is required for Sencha Cmd packages to work.
//@require @packageOverrides

//
    Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src'
});
//

```
Ext.application({
name: 'appointMeDr',

requires: [
'Ext.MessageBox','Ext.device.Connection','appointMeDr.SessionInfo',
'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage','Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
],

views: [
'Main','homePage.Home','viewsTab.FindDrTab','viewsTab.SettingTab',
'profile.user_profile','userAppointment.PatientAppointment',
'doctorViews.MainDr','doctorViews.drAppointment.DrAppointment','doctorViews.doctorProfile.BlockPatient',
'doctorViews.tabViews.DrProfileTab',
'MyPicker','Utils',
'signUp.UserSignUp','signUp.SignUp',
'guardianView.GuardianPatient','guardianView.guardianProfile.GuardianProfile','guardianView.MainGuardian',    
'attendant.MainAttendant','attendant.tabViews.AttendantProfileTab','HealthyTips'

],
models:[
'SearchDr','fixedAppointment','Patient','Login','user','DoctorModel','AppointmentModel','Guardian','DoctorDetail',
'doctorAppointment','Attendant','HealthyTipModel'
],
stores:[
'SearchDocResults','AppointmentResults','Patients','Users','OfflineUser','Doctors','Guardians','DoctorDetailsStore',
'doctorAppointments','AttendantStore','BlockPatients','TimeSlots','HealthyTips'
],
controllers: [
'LoginController','MainController','DoctorController','UserSignUp','AppointmentController','AttendantController',
'GuardianController'

],

icon: {
    '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

isIconPrecomposed: true,

startupImage: {
    '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
    '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
    '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
    '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
    '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
    '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
},

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
   // Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('appointMeDr.view.homePage.Home'));
    // Initialize the main view
   // Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('appointMeDr.view.Main'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function(buttonId) {
            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

});

Comment: We need much more information. And some code.

Comment: ok i m going to give it

Comment: i have deployed sencha app to android it produced app.js file. but i dont know anything about it its a bunch of code cant be pasted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of hard work i solved it by myself.Remove all warnings even if "",""(comma generates it) and thats it. Problem solved :)
happy coding

Answer (score 2):

We don't know what you want to do, but I try something :

I think you call connection.type property before "**deviceready**" event.

From phonegap doc :

> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should
>   use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the
>   native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However,
>   JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web
>   application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function
>   before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded.
>   After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova
>   function.

So try this :

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT** : now we have more information, I think this answer is useless for you :/